# Is it possible to get data from a webpage in real-time to an excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to create an Excel Tool that would act as a Monitoring Tool for our agents on the floor.

Right now we don't have an exclusive WFM tool that would monitor and call out agents with their activities and productivity, the only thing we have is a dashboard to view all agents status and the durations of their status or calls. This is a web-based viewer of our dialer that would only shows agents with their current status but they won't trigger or notify if an agent is going over our set thresholds for their wrap up time, over breaks or lunch.
[image]

Currently, I have an existing excel file that would look up values from another sheet to populate the table with information that I need such as the name of agent, their current status and current duration of the call.

The another sheet I've mentioned above is a blank sheet where I would simply paste all the data from the webpage of our dialer. So basically I am just doing copy-paste method where I am selecting all the contents from this webpage which is our dialer and pasting it in on the blank excel sheet that I created and the table that I made will find all the values that I setup from that blank sheet. [image]

I really don't have enough knowledge but I still tried Data>Get Data>From Web and I am not getting anything.

I tried pasting the web link, but I don't seem to pull up any data.

I know as I've mentioned, I don't really have enough knowledge and maybe I need some basics doing this method.

What I would like to happen is if there's a way to link a webpage, sync its data to an excel sheet and is it possible to make it real-time so that way I can have an improvised WFM Tool that would help me monitor our agents activities?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from the Internet through a standard mechanism (Data >Get Data > From Web) is not always successful. Excel can recognize tables on a web page, but not always in the way that the human eye recognizes them.

Actually, there are two options here:

1. write a macro that parses specifically those pages from which you are currently getting data manually (“*…I am just doing copy-paste method…*”).
2. prepare web pages so that data from them can be automatically downloaded via Data >Get Data>From Web via standard Excel functionality.
   Both require programming specifically for your task.

For example, I could write a parser, but for this I need access to the web page from which you are copying and pasting.

Or the programmer who wrote the web page can create new pages with the same data, but in a format that Excel understands. But this programmer needs to specify exactly how to design web pages.